# SSH Key being passed even though I don't want them to

Tags: ssh

My config:

- Server A is running Windows and Cygwin.
- Server B is a Linux box.

I exchanged `ssh` keys from:

```
B-->A and A-->A
```

And had passwordless `ssh` working.

Fast forward, Cygwin was buggy so I just reinstalled OpenSSH in Cygwin.

The problem.
I can no longer SSH from `B-->A`, or `A-->A`, getting the connection closed immediately.

Here is the output when trying to establish a connection:

```
$ ssh root@localhost
Connection closed by ::1 port 22

$ ssh root@A both give 
Connection closed by ::1 port 22
```

Running `ssh -vvv` gave a hint that it's trying to pass the outdated SSH-keys now (and not going to password prompt), so when I run:

```
ssh -o 'PubkeyAuthentication no' root@localhost
ssh -o 'PubkeyAuthentication no' root@A
```

I get a password prompt and I am granted access.

I tried creating an `/etc/hosts.allow` file, and cleaned up `known_hosts` and `authorized_hosts`, but still, I can't get vanilla 'ssh root@server' working just into server A.

I can even exchange `ssh` keys again using:

```
ssh-copy-id -o 'PubkeyAuthentication no' root@A
```

Where it sends the keys, but trying passwordless `ssh` after it doesn't work (with connection closed as if it's passing the old keys).

The ultimate goal is to get passwordless `ssh` working again from `B-->A`, and `A-->A`.

Any ideas?

Comment: did you remove the old key from the server or did you disable the remote account? From the look of it, the sever actually accepted authentication using the old key and then the remote server terminated connection after authentication because the account aren't configured with a working shell. To properly disable an account, you need to configure the server to reject authentication, not just disable the shell.

Comment: I removed the keys. But the shell works fine with the -o 'PubkeyAuthentication no' option. I'm not actually sure if this is a client or server problem to be honest.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "Running ssh -vvv gave a hint that it's trying to pass the outdated SSH-keys now (and not going to password prompt)" ..  Can you paste in what from that log gave you that hint. Perhaps you can specify the correct key with -i so `ssh -i id_rsa_blah1`    Also, can you run the ssh  server with server side debugging, something like `/usr/sbin/sshd -dD` that can give more info than ssh -vvv.